# Project Won't Compile

Tags: c#, c, silverlight, xaml, compiler-errors

I was modifying some icons, ran my project before and everything was fine, I tried again later and this happened.

[image]
I have no clue what's wrong because I didn't modify any code, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks
Zaroth

Link to Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nNq.png

> Error  1   The "CreateRiaClientFilesTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8956dcc7a600871' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8956dcc7a600871' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8956dcc7a600871' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>      at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods()
>      at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.EnsureHostCreated()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.CreateObject(Type type, Boolean failIfExists)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.CreateRiaClientFilesTask.GenerateClientProxies()
>      at Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.CreateRiaClientFilesTask.ExecuteInternal()
>      at Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.RiaClientFilesTask.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   Fsc.Feenics.MasterControl.Client.Silverlight
>
> Error  2   The "CreateRiaClientFilesTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8956dcc7a600871' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8956dcc7a600871' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8956dcc7a600871' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Desaware.MachineLicense40' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Comment: So what is the actual error that you are getting - the screenshot is just a blur to me even looking at the image via the link

Comment: Well something has changed, and it would seem to be a reference somewhere given the error message. Do a diff with the code before the changes. Pay attention to the solution and project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the looks of it, you are missing a DLL or reference the DLL is using.  You probably cleaned up some files on PC and deleted those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was not missing any DLL. I had to clean the **Temporary ASP.NET Files** folder to get rid of this (specifically, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`).